# How can I make my site open Instagram in-app?

Tags: html, mobile, instagram, redirect

Hi I'd like my site to automatically redirect to an Instagram page. I found this site that kinda show the code I need, but if differs for Android / iPhone. Now is my question is there a way to identify which smartphone to user is using. And automatically open the app, using the right code for their OS?

using this site https://app.urlgeni.us/#/

```
<a href="intent://instagram.com/_u/kopstootkompanen/#Intent;package=com.instagram.android;scheme=https;end"><img src="https://q-play.nl/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/android-logo-png-transparent.png" style="width:182px; height:186px" title="Android" alt="Android"></a>
```

Using the code I currently have the user first needs to choose their OS, but I don't want that.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need that. Each phone has its own route to app considering the url. If you open some http://*.facebook.com/* URL, the phone is asked to open it on a browser or at the Facebook app. This is a native feature on smartphones, and the user may choose always to open the instagram.com URLs via app.

So, I guess this is the best way of doing that, even because your users may not even have the app installed for N reasons.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the href as instagram:// and the user has the app installed (and they're on mobile) then it should open instagram